# Shortcut to "mate-screenshot -a" not working in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate, screenshot

Just installed MATE on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to get to mate-screenshot the same behaviour as gnome-screenshot does in Unity: just press Shift+Print to choose the portion of the screen that you want to capture. The corresponding command to be executed under MATE should be "mate-screenshot -a", executing it manually works, but trying to set it as custom shortcut doesn't work, it does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried that: set Shift+Print_Screen to `mate-screenshot -a` , which worked fine. Is there any possibility of hardware issues ? ( meaning, can you try another keyboard ?)

Answer (score 8):

There is still an [opened issue](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues/37) for that.
tl;dr: this is a timing problem with focus.
workaround:

```
bash -c "sleep 0.1 && mate-screenshot -a"
```

Comment: Even almost 3 years later and on Manjaro, this issue still seems to exist. Sleeping for 0.1s fixes that.

Comment: Debian 11, same bug .

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced your issue and with help from @Serg and @Seth I figured out how to fix it.

In the shortcut you have set DISPLAY to match your environment. First check the variable:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

and take note of the output. For me it's `:0.0`

Originally I suggested using this command in the shortcut setting:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 mate-screenshot -a"
```

Replacing `:0.0` to match the output you got when you checked the variable

But @DavidFoerster pointed out in a comment that the more efficient and proper way is to use

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0 mate-screenshot -a
```

Which might make it a touch faster.

Comment: The canonical way to run a command with a particular environment variable value is via the `env` command, e. g. `env DISPLAY=:0.0 mate-screenshot -a`. No need to resort to the relatively bloated Bash (or even Dash). Otherwise +1.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround if using Compiz and you can give up Windows captures.

Go into Compiz Mate Compatibility settings and change the Window screenshot command line to mate-screenshot -a. It will then work if you are already using compiz (not Marco). The shortcut key combo is ALT + Printscreen.

[image: compiz settings]